# How to inject a HttpClient<GitHubService> similar to ILogger<T>

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, dependency-injection, dotnet-httpclient

With HttpClientFactory we can configure dependency injection to create and manage the lifetime of HttpClients, but this creates a lot of code understanding and transparency problems:

```
public class GitHubService
{
    private readonly HttpClient _client;
    private readonly string _repositoryName;

    public GitHubService(HttpClient client, string repositoryName)
    {
        _client = client;
        _repositoryName = repositoryName;
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<GitHubIssue>> GetAspNetDocsIssues()
    {
        var response = await _client.GetAsync(
            $"/repos/aspnet/{_repositoryName}/issues?state=open&sort=created&direction=desc");

        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        using var responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
        return await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync
            <IEnumerable<GitHubIssue>>(responseStream);
    }
}
```

Then in `Startup.cs` we configure DI:

```
services.AddHttpClient<GitHubService>(c =>
{
    c.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.github.com/");
    // Github API versioning
    c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/vnd.github.v3+json");
    // Github requires a user-agent
    c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "HttpClientFactory-Sample");
});
```

However, this raises a number of problems:

1. If I share the `GitHubService` code with someone, they will not understand that the class is using a non-standard `HttpClient`. To understand the logic of building requests, headers, authorization, you need to additionally study the `Startup.cs` class.
2. You might think that we are setting up an implementation of only the `HttpClient` for the `GitHubService` class. However, in fact, we are setting up dependency injection for the entire GitHubService class, without the possibility of managing its lifecycle and creation factory.
3. If the `GitHubService` class requires additional parameters in the constructor, we cannot configure them, because we do not have access to control the creation of the object.

Why not just inject a typed `HttpClient<GitHubService>` (like it does with `ILogger<T>`) that will not affect the main class and make it clear that you are not using a regular `HttpClient`? How can this problem be solved?

```
public class GitHubService
{
    private readonly HttpClient<GitHubService> _client;
    private readonly string _repositoryName;

    public GitHubService(HttpClient<GitHubService> client, string repositoryName)
    {
        _client = client;
        _repositoryName = repositoryName;
    }

    // Code removed for brevity.
}
```

Comment: I would instead inject an IHttpClientFactory into GitHubService, because even injecting an `HttpClient<T>` could still be [error prone](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/36067) as long as the injected http clients are not scoped.

Comment: Creating a solution with a custom `HttpClient<T>`will likely be very complex. To prevent all kinds of trouble (such as DNS misses) you will have to let the default `IHttpClientFactory` create `HttpClient` instances, but this means your `HttpClient<T>` can't derive from `HttpClient`. Thus this means your `HttpClient<T>` should wrap HttpClient, but that will force you to duplicate the `HttpClient`'s API into `HttpClient<T>`; that's possibly a lot of code.

Comment: [Here's an example](https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector/issues/654#issuecomment-454051502) that demonstrates using `IHttpClientFactory` instead of relying on typed clients.

Comment: @Steven HttpMessageHandler default lifetime is 2 minutes, so if in the application the requests do not go often than every 2 minutes, you will not get any benefit from reusing the HttpMessageHandler through the factory

Comment: If you're sure the those limitations will work fine within the context of your application: go for it. But you might want to document this for the next developer who will be working on the application two years from now.